# Why is Ant using Jar library twice?

Tags: java, android, ant, jar

I ran across a problem with building .apk file using Ant.
Before I added game.jar to libs folder everything was allright and Ant succesfully produced .apk file.

After I added game.jar to libs folder trouble starts. During [dex] phase everything seems still allright.

```
[dex] input: path\to\project\libs\game.jar
```

But in [apkbuilder] phase Ant failed with this message:

```
[apkbuilder] Found duplicate file for APK: classes.dex
[apkbuilder] Origin 1: path\to\project\bin\classes.dex
[apkbuilder] Origin 2: path\to\project\libs\game.jar
```

game.jar is added only to libs folder.

Any idea what could cause the problem? Do I need specify some setting?
Can I prevent Ant from using game.jar in [apkbuilder] phase ?